# How can I add first child and last child to my sections?

Tags: css, css-selectors

On one of my pages I have five similar divs and I wish to add a border to the top aswell to the bottom of the first and the last div.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="info_box">
    Text content is here
</div
<div class="info_box">
    Text content is here
</div>
```

... And so on...

**CSS**:

```
.info_box{
    top: 8em;
    float: left;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0.5);
}
.info_box:first-child{
    border-top: 1 px solid #666;
}
.info_box:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1 px solid #666;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: aha. Is there any way I can target the first and the last div of the five using class and not id? - Or do I have to make an id for each of the elements?

Comment: You do it via `nth-child`

Comment: You really wouldn't do it via nth-child, even though technically you could. So by no means is it an off the wall suggestion. The better way is to do first-child and last child. The reason being that the number of info_boxes may change. If it does then your code will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

just add class "with-border" to the first and last div (or any div you want to have a border), and then add this to your css:

```
.with-border {
    border-bottom: 1 px solid #666;
}
```

So your first and last divs will be:

```
<div class="info_box with-border">
    Text content is here
</div>
```

Comment: This would solve it, but it really isn't necessary to create a class just for this. I would recommend just fixing the issues as noted in my response below.

Answer (score 1):

How you are doing it with the CSS is absolutely fine, except you have two errors.

You need to remove the space between the 1 and px like the following.

```
.info_box:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
}
.info_box:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
```

In addition you need to close your divs, you are missing a closing >

```
<div class="info_box">
    Text content is here
</div>
<div class="info_box">
    Text content is here
</div>
```

That should solve it for you.

Comment: Also, background declaration has a mistake. Should be `background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);` (last value had two decimal separators).

Comment: Good catch, there is also that mistake.